# spring Postgres DB from console connection

Tags: linux, spring, postgresql

my spring app uses PostgreSQL as the default DB. The question is, can I connect to this DB and manage it from the Linux console because I hate GUI.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html